# Betti number and torsion coefficient

Tags: gap

Is there any function in GAP to calculate Betti number and torsion coefficient of a group given?

Thanks.

Comment: Any more specific details about the group?

Comment: Also, have you tried `??Betti` in GAP to see all help system items containing a substring `Betti` - does it give any useful hints?

Comment: Thanks for the hint Alexander, I'll check it in a few days.

Comment: Did you find out something interesting, perhaps to be able to post an answer to your own question here?